# How can I use WebStorm to debug my node application across multiple processes?

Tags: debugging, node.js, intellij-idea, child-process, webstorm

My node application makes a call to `child_process.exec`, at which point I can't 'step into' each line of code any more, and none of the breakpoints in the node app being started by `.exec` seem to work.

How can I used WebStorm to debug this application as though calls to `child_process.exec` were like any other function call?

Answer (score 4):

'exec' starts a new process so you need to pass '--debug=port' command line argument to it.  Your code will look like `child_process.exec('node --debug=8787 ' + __dirname + '/childProcess.js');`

After that you can create a NodeJS Remote Debug configuration in Run | 'Edit Configurations' dialog and press 'Debug' button to connect to the child process.